# Multiple POSTs in a Django unit test

Tags: django, unit-testing

I am writing unit tests to validate a profile avatar module. So, I have a form that allows a user to upload an avatar. If one exists, it simply replaces the current one.

In my test, I do the following (the class setup logs a user in - not shown here):

```
    f = open('testfile1.jpg')
    data = {'image':f}
    response = self.client.post('/profile/uploadavatar/',data)
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
    self.assertEqual(self.user1.get_profile().avatar.image.name, u'uploads/images/testfile1.jpg')
    f.close()

    f = open('testfile2.jpg')
    data = {'image':f}
    response = self.client.post('/profile/uploadavatar/',data)
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
    self.assertEqual(self.user1.get_profile().avatar.image.name, u'uploads/images/testfile2.jpg')
    f.close()
```

The second assertEqual to test for avatar image name always fails because it is still set to the first filename (testfile1.jpg). However when I test this manually the code does what I think it should, which is replace the old avatar with the new one.

Am I doing something wrong? I'm new to the django unit tests so I may be missing something very simple...

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Reload the user object between uploads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "self.user1" object, along with the profile, are cached at the beginning.

Reload the user/profile objects between actions to see updated data.

(Pulled up from the comments.)